# noVNC customised HTML with Jmeter - custom local scaling in settings and hiding fluxbox toolbar

Tags: docker, jmeter, performance-testing, x11, novnc

I tried customising noVNC html to better scale the workspace to hide grey area(toolbar) of fluxbox, I was successful in that as you can see in below image.

[image] and default screen is smaller than this

this is my dockerfile for customized version of noVNC- image name in docker hub repo -> **ddddv1/nonvcj**

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN \
    # Install required packages
    echo "http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk --update --upgrade add \
      bash \
      fluxbox \
      git \
      supervisor \
      xvfb \
      x11vnc \
      && \
    # Install noVNC
    # customised github repo code -> https://github.com/gg-gg-v1/noVNCJmeter.git
    git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/gg-gg-v1/noVNCJmeter.git /root/noVNC && \
    git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/novnc/websockify /root/noVNC/utils/websockify && \
    rm -rf /root/noVNC/.git && \
    rm -rf /root/noVNC/utils/websockify/.git && \
    apk del git && \
    sed -i -- "s/ps -p/ps -o pid | grep/g" /root/noVNC/utils/launch.sh

# here adding  external site-packages since default python3.9 does not have site-packages
ADD site-packages/ /usr/lib/python3.9/
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
EXPOSE 8080

# Setup environment variables ~/.fluxbox/init
ENV HOME=/root \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    DISPLAY=:0.0 \
    DISPLAY_WIDTH=1024 \
    DISPLAY_HEIGHT=768

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

But when I run Jmeter inside my customized noVNC docker, again good scaling is gone and I am back with small scaling which does not look good, see below image for that

[image]

why this went to small scale and there is a black color border which is wrapping jmeter ? can we  launch Jmeter in good scaling ?

I am using above custsomised docker image(**ddddv1/nonvcj**) in below docker file and launching it in docker

```
 
FROM ddddv1/nonvcj
 
RUN \
    apk add --no-cache curl openjdk8-jre bash nss \
    # && apk add ca-certificates \
    # && update-ca-certificates \
    # && apk add --no-cache nss \
    && curl -L https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.1.tgz >  /tmp/jmeter.tgz \
    && mkdir -p /opt \
    && tar -xvf /tmp/jmeter.tgz -C /opt \
    && rm /tmp/jmeter.tgz \
    && cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d \
    && echo '[program:jmeter]' >> supervisord.conf \
    && echo 'command=/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/./jmeter' >> supervisord.conf \
    && echo 'autorestart=true' >> supervisord.conf
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/
RUN export JAVA_HOME
```

1. Am I using something outdated here (apk or alpine, will it make difference) or some extra thing ?
2. How can I remove or hide the fluxbox toolbar [Workspace 1] which is shown in the downside, I manually did hide toolbar with fluxbox configurations but I want to do this with docker file any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is `good scaling` but it seems that you're [setting VNC resolution](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-change-the-vnc-server-resolution-in-linux/) to 1024x768

```
DISPLAY_WIDTH=1024 \
DISPLAY_HEIGHT=768
```

and your desktop/browser resolution is higher, just adjust this to match your browser window and that would be it.

With regards to hiding the toolbar you can create [`~/.fluxbox/init`](https://github.com/wbotelhos/fluxbox/blob/master/files/init) file and put `session.screen0.toolbar.visible=false` line there, something like:

```
echo 'session.screen0.toolbar.visible=false' >> ~/.fluxbox/init
```

Also it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, running JMeter in docker in GUI mode doesn't make a lot of sense as GUI is for tests development and debugging and it will be way more convenient to do this locally instead of working in a browser window as you're able to use keyboard shortcuts and context menus.

If you're going to use [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) or [k8s](https://kubernetes.io/) for tests scaling you will need to [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) which makes your image not suitable for this purpose.